# Как сохраняются методы в делегатах и как вызывать разные методы?

Tags: c#, .net

Разбираюсь с делегатами, возник вопрос который не совсем понимаю.
Когда мы создали объект делегата то можем добавлять, или удалять из него методы которые подходят по сигнатуре.

```
delegate int IntSomeDelegate(int x, int y);
IntSomeDelegate somDelegate = (x, y) => (GetMultiply(x, y));

somDelegate += GetMultiply;
somDelegate += GetSum;
somDelegate -= GetMultiply;
```

Если мы добавляем или удаляем из делегата методы, то они должны хранится в какой то структуре данных, из которой потом можно дергать нужный нам метод через делегат. Как обращаться к нужному методу через делегат ? Или я совсем все неправильно понял ?

Comment: При вызове делегата вызываются все методы ему назначенные. Чтобы вызвать делегат, просто вызовите его `IntSomeDelegate(2, 5);`. Вызвать отдельный метод, хранящийся в делегате получится только через рефлексию.

Comment: Вероятнее всего там хранятся просто ссылки на методы и вряд ли си шарп на это способен т.к. с ссылками он практически не работает. Чисто теоретически это нужно залезть в unsafe code. И там обратиться к области памяти где хранится делегат с неким отступом..... Но это все звучит в любом случае как костыли. Просто потому, что делегаты не предназначены для такого использования и я настоятельно рекомендую так не делать, даже, если найдешь способ.

Comment: @aepot: Вроде ж и без рефлексии можно: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5NTGZp

Comment: @VladD почему-то я думал, что `GetInvocationList()` - это где-то в рефлексии, ну ок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы объявляете переменную делегатного типа, на самом деле вы получаете объект, производный от `MulticastDelegate`. Исходники этого класса можно посмотреть [тут](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/MulticastDelegate.cs).

Вам обычно не должно быть нужно «разобрать» `MulticastDelegate` на составляющие его одиночные делегаты, вы вызываете всю группу делегатов вместе:

```cs
Action d = () => Console.WriteLine("delegate 1");
d += () => Console.WriteLine("delegate 2");
d();
```

Выводит следующее:

> delegate 1
> delegate 2

Но если очень хочется, можно получить список по частям, используя [`GetInvocationList()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist?view=net-5.0):

```cs
foreach (Action part in d.GetInvocationList())
    part();
```

Результат будет такой же, даже порядок делегатов гарантированно тот же.

Проверка: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xadzcr